# Spinnaker: LDAP authorization setup

Tags: spinnaker

hello: when trying to setup authorization using LDAP, i am getting below error, any suggestions:

````
2017-09-27 21:52:30.931  WARN 1 --- [           main] 
c.n.s.f.p.internal.ClouddriverService    : [] Cache initialization 
failed: 
com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException: getAccounts failed and fallback failed.
at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$16.call(AbstractCommand.java:811)
at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$16.call(AbstractCommand.java:785)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction$1.onError(OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction.java:99)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:71)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:71)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:71)
at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$DeprecatedOnFallbackHookApplication$1.onError(AbstractCommand.java:1514)
at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$FallbackHookApplication$1.onError(AbstractCommand.java:1404)
at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:314)
at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:306)
at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)```
````

here is my ldap config:

`auth:
  groupMembership:
    service: ldap
    ldap:
      url: ldap://10.10.10.21
      managerDn: cn=admn,dc=testlab,dc=corp
      managerPassword: adm543
      groupSearchBase: ou=groups,dc=testlab,dc=corp
      groupSearchFilter: member={0},dc=testlab,dc=corp
      groupRoleAttributes: cn
      userDnPattern: uid={0},ou=testlab,ou='service accounts'
      userSearchBase: dc=testlab,dc=corp
      userSearchFilter: ''`

Comment: Also tried this config as suggested on spinnaker slack:  `auth:
      groupMembership:
        service: ldap
        ldap:
          enabled: true
          url: ldap://company.net:123/dc=company,dc=net
          managerDn: serviceaccount@company.net
          managerPassword: 
          userSearchFilter: (sAMAccountName={0})
          groupSearchFilter: (member={0})
          groupSearchBase: OU=Groups,OU=Accounts`

Answer (score 1):

userSearchFilter is overwriting userDnPattern. And it looks like you are searching only for users in the service accounts ou.

Try something like this

```
auth:
  groupMembership:
    service: ldap
    ldap:
      # Connection
      url: ldap://10.10.10.21
      managerDn: cn=admn,dc=testlab,dc=corp
      managerPassword: adm543
      # Groups
      groupSearchBase: ou=groups,dc=testlab,dc=corp
      groupSearchFilter: member={0},dc=testlab,dc=corp
      groupRoleAttributes: cn
      # Users
      userSearchBase: uid={0},ou=users,dc=testlab,dc=corp
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work like this.

```
       ldap:
          roleProviderType: LDAP
          url: ldap://##.###.##.###:389
          managerDn: CN=myUser,OU=Users_ServicesAdmin,OU=Usuarios_Especiais,DC=myDc,DC=intranet
          managerPassword: #####
          userSearchFilter: sAMAccountName={0}
          userSearchBase: dc=uolcorp,dc=intranet
          groupSearchBase: ou=Grupos,ou=Grupos,DC=corp,DC=intranet
          groupSearchFilter: member={0}
          groupRoleAttributes: cn
```